# Pass Kerberos keytab from StringIO to kinit

Tags: python-2.7, kerberos

I am writing a small Python utility that stores a Kerberos v5 keytab in a StringIO object. I want to avoid storing said keytab anywhere on the machine's disk.

Therefore, I would very much want to invoke `kinit` like this (`split()` and `subprocess()` to follow):

```
command = "/usr/bin/kinit -V -c {0} -t {1} {2}@{3}".format(cache, ticket, loginUser, kerberosDomain)
```

where the ticket is:

```
ticket = StringIO.StringIO(data)
```

But [kinit](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/user/user_commands/kinit.html) doesn't really like it. Its [source file](https://github.com/trustedanalytics/kerberos/blob/master/src/clients/kinit/kinit.c) says:

```
925    /* Ensure we can be driven from a pipe */
```

Does anyone have experience with driving `kinit` from a pipe, and specifically how to inject the ticket into (presumably) its stdin?

Alternatively, can a `StringIO` be wrapped into something like `mmap` to behave like a "real" file to `kinit`?

Thanks!

PS: A very interesting discussion I read as I was posting this question:
[Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542)

Comment: If you are so paranoid about storing a keytab on disk, why use a shared cache, instead of creating private Kerberos tickets on the fly? _(and BTW I suppose that you don't use the default `FILE:` cache, but instead something like `KEYRING:`...)_

Comment: @samson-scharfrichter Processes in the same API:// cache need to access the ticket from the context of the logged in $user, as this is on macOS. macOS has its own security model when it comes to who can access what in terms of Kerberos ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION9)). The above script is invoked in a similar context.

Comment: Some people don't bother with `kinit` and create/cache the ticket with a pure Python interface, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786908/java-gss-api-service-ticket-not-saved-in-credentials-cache-using-java

Comment: @samson-scharfrichter Yup, I was looking into a Python-only GSS interface since I would love to use that (and it'll likely satisfy the StringIO requirement above), but what I found [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kerberos) for Python-2.7: 1) is poorly documented, 2) seems to be aimed at authenticating against Apache https protected via kerberos (with auth redirects) and 3) does not take a credentials ticket but a plaintext username and password. :-(